# maven-plugin-plugin helpmojo breaking change?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a Maven plugin which is a year or two old. Recently I noticed that the `helpmojo` goal of `maven-plugin-plugin` appears to not be working.

It **is** working for an older version of the plugin - I'm not sure at which release it stopped working.

By "*not working*" I mean that the `help` goal is not correctly generated and is not found when called using `mvn <plugin>:help`, whilst other goals are found.

`HelpMojo.java` is created under `target/generated-sources/plugin`, but no entry appears in the the plugin descriptor, `plugin.xml` in the final .jar.

Has a bug or breaking change been introduced in a recent version of `maven-plugin-plugin` or have I changed something which has prevented it from working as a side-effect? (For example, the plugin project is now multi-module.)

The `pom.xml` config looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generated-helpmojo</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you show the pom? Do you use annotations?

Comment: The whole pom is very lengthy, so I showed only the part I thought relevant. Is there another section of it I should post?
The other Mojos in the plugin all use the old doclet style, and they are working just fine.

Comment: @khmarbaise Your comment about annotations gave me a clue. I looked at the release and JIRA history for maven-plugin-plugin, and looked in my own svn log for version changes in maven-plugin-plugin. It seems that version 3.1 works, but version 3.2 is broken, for the 'helpmojo' goal. If someone can confirm this, I'll accept the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to downgrade to version 3.1